# MvvmCross - Xamarin - Cannot create any MvxListView anymore

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I'm facing a very strange behaviour with mvvmcross and xamarin. Since today i can't populate any MvxListView, MvxLinearLayout etc anymore.

Here is what i know :

- All views of those types i created earlier (the last one working was created last week) still works fine and are populated
- If i try to create a new one it won't display any child item.
- If i set a background color or any stylish element to my view i will be able to see it. But if i do the same for the item template it
  won't show up.
- If I click on my MvxListView, the output will say this :

> 07-12 16:29:09.154 W/AbsListView(26069): Intent to operate on
>   non-exist data, childcount=0, mFirstPosition=0, mItemCount=0, adapter
>   count=0,
>   mAdapter=md5bf0126c95bf9fc0db24c02c9adb4cfa7.MvxAdapter@3fbd5398,
>   action=1, mActivePointerId=0, mScrollY=0,
>   this=mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxListView{12a517f1
>   V.ED.VC......... 15,15-196,912}

- If i add a new MvxListView near an old one, bind it to the same dataset, i will still encounter the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea ? I highly suspect the last Xamarin Update to be causing this, so i upgraded Mvmmcross believing they fixed it as the last update is one day old (07/11/2016) but this didn't help.

**Update** :

After more investigations i can tell that i'm not able to create new custom bindings neither. Looks like the binding engine is absolutely dead for my project. All bindings done before monday 07/11/2016 are working, any new one won't and i haven't found any workaround yet

**Update 2 :**

As requested here is some code, but i would like to say that the very same bug will occur even if i use a normal MvxListView with itemSource binded on a list of string or any kind of dataset.

I just created this custom view to use it as a workaround, believing that regisetering my own custom binding could somehow "override" the broken binding system.

*WokingMvxListView* :

```
public class WorkingMvxListView : MvxListView
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel> _timings;
        //TimingControlModel is some class containing timespan and floats etc
        public ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel> Timings
        {
            get
            {
                return _timings;
            }
            set
            {
                _timings = value;
                ItemSource = value;
            }
        }
        public WorkingMvxListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {

        }
        public WorkingMvxListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter) : base (context, attrs, adapter)
        {

        }
        protected WorkingMvxListView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer): base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }
    }
```

*TargetBinding* :

```
public class MvxVogofCustomListViewTimersBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        private readonly bool _isVogofWorkingMvxListViewBinding;

        public MvxVogofCustomListViewTimersBinding(WorkingMvxListView target) : base(target)
        {
            if(target==null)
            {
                MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Error WorkingMvxListView is null in MvxVogofMediaControllerFileNameBinding");
                return;
            }
            _isVogofWorkingMvxListViewBinding = target is WorkingMvxListView;
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel>);
            }
        }
        public override void SetValue(object value)
        {
            base.SetValue(value);
        }
        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {
            ((WorkingMvxListView)target).Timings = (ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel>)value;
        }

        public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
        {
            get { return  MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
        }

    }
```

*Setup.cs* :

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
        {
            registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<WorkingMvxListView>("Timings", (workingMvxListView) => new MvxVogofCustomListViewTimersBinding(workingMvxListView)));
        }
```

*ViewModel :*

```
 private ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel> _timings;
        public ObservableCollection<TimingControlModel> Timings
        {
            get
            {
                return _timings;
            }
            set
            {
                _timings = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Timings);
            }
        }
```

*View.axml :*

```
<Vogof.Droid.Views.CustomViews.WorkingMvxListView
 android:id="@+id/TimersList"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/White"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:divider="#DDDDDD"
 android:dividerHeight="4px"
 local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/template_timer_item"
 local:MvxBind="Timings Timings" />
<!--Yes i know Timings Timings sounds terrible, but it is for test purposes-->
```

*ItemTemplate.axml :*

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#050506"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text TimeToDisplay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

**Update 3 :**

By adding ItemSource=value in my WorkingMvxListView, after downgrading Xamarin  to 4.0.3, removing all my android sdk's, installing the ones recommended [here](http://[https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63356/the-file-obj-debug-android-bin-packaged-resources-does-not-exist])  by angelocarlotto, i'm finally able to have data in my WorkingMvxListViewModel !

But the real problem, that i can't bind on normal MvxListView, still persist

Comment: Can you share some of your code for the new `MvxListView` you added, and the code how you added this? This bugs seems to be reported at [github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1395) as well:

Comment: I will add some code. I'm the one who reported the bug at github ^^

Comment: Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: It is a debug build

Comment: Added every piece of code i believe that would help you guys, thank you for your help!

Comment: From what thread are you updating your ObservableCollection?

Comment: My ObservableCollection is updated every time i set a property called Step in the same ViewModel, as the Step property contains some data used to create the elements of my ObservableCollection.
If i add a breakpoint on Timings setter in WorkingMvxListView, it's reached, value does contains my elements; but yet i still have  "Intent to operate on non-exist data, childcount=0" in the output

Comment: Just keep in mind any additions, moves and removals on an ObservableCollection needs to happen on the UI thread.

Comment: My Observable collection is just an example, i have the very same problem with a List<Foo>